# Singular query won’t return nested arrays

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a query that tries to fetch a single document, here is the resolver for that query.

```
const singleDoc = async (_parent, args, context, info) => {
    try {
        return await context.prisma.doc({ id: args.docId },info )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

If I call the query in GraphQL, it returns this:

```
  "data": {
    "singleDoc": {
      "name": "Sample doc",
      "teams": null,
      "description": "This holds doc description"
    }
  }
}
```

I queried for the **teams** field but they weren’t returned.

I feel like there is something wrong with the query resolver? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have other queries that function using `context.prisma.doc`? When you log `context.prisma` do you see your db instance?

Comment: @technicallynick yes I can see the db instance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve by using **graphQL** **fragments**

*Fragment*

```
const docFragment = `
    fragment DocWithDetails on Doc {
        name
        teams{
            id
            role
          }
    }`
```

Then I passed the graphQL fragment into the resolver. This was I was able to retrieve the nested relations

```
const singleDoc = async (_parent, args, context, info) => {
    try {
        return await context.prisma.doc({ id: args.docId }).$fragment(docFragment)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```